# WCF REST Security Options for clients not all using .NET

Tags: android, wcf, security, xamarin.ios, wcf-security

We have a WCF RESTful service which is to be consumed by Android (Java) and iPhone/iPad devices running MonoTouch (.NET)

What security options can WCF support which Android (Java) and iPhone (.NET) take advantage of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For interoperability reason the best security option is HTTPS for confidentiality and integrity and either custom or HTTP Basic authentication.